# resultset.next() with 1 row taking too much time

Tags: performance, jdbc

I have a problem with performance while querying Sybase from a Java program. I have placed multiple logs to debug and found that the query itself is taking an expected amount of time , however , the call to resultset.next() seems to be taking an equal amount of time!

Query is something like "select count(*) from" and always returns 1 row. And my Java code is something like.

```
resultset = statement.executeQuery();
logger.debug("After fetching resultset");
while(resultset.next(){
     numberOfAccounts = resultset.getInt(1);
}
logger.debug("After looping resultset::" +numberOfAccounts)
```

Any ideas on why its taking on an average 200 milliseconds between the above 2 logs? Confirmed that the `statement.executeQuery()` is taking aroud 150 ms.

I checked google and everyone seemed to be talking about increasing statement `fetchSize()`. But in this case there is only 1 row. Also I'm printing the query before executing so pretty sure its returning 1 row only.

Comment: Network roundtrips? Also it is entirely possible that the query is really executed at first fetch, instead of at execute time.

Comment: Added an EDIT above as executeQuery itself is taking around 150ms. Just to clarify , do you mean that its possible that due to network slowness , its taking that much time to fetch the result of the executed query from the DB?

Comment: There can be several reasons, a `next()` will trigger a fetch to retrieve one or more rows from the server. So that will take at least the network roundtrip (ping) + serverside processing. And as I said, an execute itself might do very little work, while the actual work is deferred until fetch time.